# How to display a date depending on data from a drop down menu?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a receipt tracker that includes each item from each receipt. Each item has an invoice number and a date.

I have a separate chart that just has the invoice number, the total amount before tax, and total after. I'm also trying to add a column that contains the date associated with each invoice number, but cannot figure out how to automatically fill the date box without manually typing in each date.

I want to be able to select an invoice number from the drop-down menu and have the date auto fill in the correct position.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_wtPIZKYQ2A4-K5dYb9VRxTatekQwKD9vJU5KwkVtj0/edit#gid=0

I honestly tried doing everything from the SUMIF function to IF to many other functions, but cannot find what function or process I'm supposed to use.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While a link to a external resource might be helpful, questions on this site shoudl be self contained. Considereing this, please add some sample and show what you have tried directly into the question body. You can use markdow to format data as tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLOOKUP` or any other lookup function.

```
=XLOOKUP(I5,A$5:A,B$5:B)
```

Or with a single formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(XLOOKUP(I5:I,A5:A,B5:B,))
```

Comment: Oh my goodness you beautiful human, thank you so much. I knew it would be something painfully easy.